# Getting TypeError when uploading file to S3 bucket using aws-amplify

Tags: amazon-s3, expo, aws-amplify

I am using aws-amplify with react-native expo.
Firstly, I created a demo app to check if s3 is working, I was successful in configuring Aws-amplify and s3 bucket on the demo application.

Now I want to use the same bucket and configs for My actual project

I followed the [amplify-docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/teams/multi-frontend/) to use one backend across multiple apps.

Then in my actual project I used:

`amplify pull --appId <myappid> --envName dev`

It was successfully pulled but when I tried to upload image, or any text like:

`const result = await Storage.put("imageName.txt", "Hello world");`

### I got the error `Error uploading file: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.byteLength')]`

One different thing I did when pulling the backend **metadata** was that I didn't use **Access Keys** but the other alternative, however I used **Access Keys** in demo project.

Did this happen because of different auth method?

Anyone knows why I am getting the error?

Help would be appreciated